# is it possible that when recyclerview load items just load one time and dont reload scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, loading

is it possible that when recyclerview load items just load one time and dont  reload scrolling?
I want to load all data before loading it to my recyclerView.

Comment: What do you mean by  dont reload scrolling?? Explain proper

Comment: This will make `RecyclerView` work as a `LinearLayout` , Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do that.

1. Load all the data (through a web service call or by any other means).
2. When data are retrieved, set them to the `RecyclerView`'s adapter and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`).
3. Use the `RecyclerView` normally (i.e. binding data objects to the views in `onBindViewHolder()`.

This way you will get what you want (having all data and not needing to load more as the user scrolls) and the benefits of the `RecyclerView`, that creates as many views as needed.