# Load all RecyclerView items at once

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Default RecyclerView feature is to load only those items which are visible and load rest of the items as needed when user scrolls the list.

But my requirement is to load all items at once.

Any idea how to achieve this.

I am loading a Book and each page has multiple images for every line.
I am loading one image per item and I need to implement auto scroll feature for which I need to calculate whole recyclerview height.

Comment: Can you please tell your purpose, so we tell you best solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025545/is-it-possible-that-when-recyclerview-load-items-just-load-one-time-and-dont-rel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible that when recyclerview load items just load one time and dont reload scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025545/is-it-possible-that-when-recyclerview-load-items-just-load-one-time-and-dont-rel)

Comment: It would be doable with a custom layout manager, but it's a lot of tough code.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of changing the default behavior of recyclerView if its possible use listView/gridView (until and unless you need StaggardGridView of recyclerView)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep Recyclerview inside NestedScrollView. In simple first all the views regarding recyclerview items, that of cards is set to NestedScrollView and the things goes perfectly.